# D callbacks in C functions

Tags: binding, lua, d

I am writing `D2` bindings for Lua.  This is in one of the Lua header files.

```
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);
```

I assume the equivalent `D2` statement would be:

```
extern(C) alias int function( lua_State* L ) lua_CFunction;
```

Lua also provides an api function:

```
void lua_pushcfunction( lua_State* L, string name, lua_CFunction func );
```

If I want to push a `D2` function does it have to be extern(C) or can I just use the function?

```
int dfunc( lua_State* L )
{
   std.stdio.writeln("dfunc");
}

extern(C) int cfunc( lua_State* L )
{
   std.stdio.writeln("cfunc");
}

lua_State* L = lua_newstate();
lua_pushcfunction(L, "cfunc", &cfunc); //This will definitely work.
lua_pushcfunction(L, "dfunc", &dfunc); //Will this work?
```

If I can only use `cfunc`, why?  I don't need to do anything like that in `C++`.  I can just pass the address of a `C++` function to `C` and everything just works.

Comment: There are some bindings that currently exsist, not sure how good they are: http://code.google.com/p/dlua/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the function must be declared as `extern (C)`.

The calling convention of functions in C and D are different, so you must tell the compiler to use the C convention with `extern (C)`. I don't know why you don't have to do this in C++.

See [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/interfaceToC.html) for more information on interfacing with C.

It's also worth noting that you can use the C style for declaring function arguments.

Comment: It's possible that C and C++ are *close enough* that it doesn't matter.

Comment: As an educated guess, I think for C++, any function that can be passed as a function pointer to C (The type of the function pointer is definable in C) will have the same calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your typedef translation is correct. OTOH have you looked at [the `htod` tool](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/htod.html)?